# Kotlin - how to find an exact instance of a class

Tags: kotlin

```
sealed class Mission(open val quests: List<Quest>) {
sealed class SubMission(override val quests: List<Quest>) : Mission(quests) {
    data class Mission1(override val quests: List<Quest>): SubMission(quests) 
    data class Mission2(override val quests: List<Quest>): SubMission(quests) 
    data class Mission3(override val quests: List<Quest>): SubMission(quests) 
} }
```

I have this structure in my code and a `List<Mission>`.

Then using a following function I would like the list to return an exact item that matches the class given in function.

`private fun getMission(currentMissionClass: KClass<Mission>): Mission {}`

So let's say I'm giving the function argument `Mission.SubMission.Mission1()` and I expect the function to return the item from `List<Mission>` that matches that exact class. Is there an easy and convenient way to do this in kotlin?

Comment: Unless `Mission1`, `Mission2` and `Mission3` have subclasses, [`filterIsInstance`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-is-instance.html) should work. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[filterIsInstance](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-is-instance.html) should work

```
private inline fun <reified T: Mission> getMission(
    list: List<Mission>, currentMissionClass: Class<T>): List<T> {
    return list.filterIsInstance<T>()
}


getMission(list, Mission1::class.java)
```

Comment: Why do you need the `currentMissionClass` argument if you have `T` reified anyway? You can just call `getMission<Mission1>(list)`, or actually just forget about the `getMission` function entirely and just use `list.filterIsInstance<MIssion1>()`

Comment: yes Joffrey, absolutely makes sense. @miltent